# Unable to trigger http.post in angular2 provider

Tags: angular

I might sound dumb but I'm a newbie in angular2.
I'm working on a project on ionic2, 
I've written an auth-service that has a function
IsEmailAvailable() for async validation on input tag.

I'm unable to fire http.post request. I've tried many tutorials. 
I know http in angular2 return Observable which has many advantages. I've tried converting the http.post to .toPromise and tried using .then too. Still no progress.

```
this.http.post(MyApp.BASE_URL+"/api/auth/email",body).map(res => res.json())
         .subscribe(
           res   => {console.warn("some thing")},
           err => { console.error("some bullshit")},
           () =>  {console.log('Authentication Complete')}
         );
```

**EDIT 1**

```
  public isEmailAvailable(control : Control) {

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      let body =  JSON.stringify({username: control.value});
      console.log(body);
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      this.http.post(MyApp.BASE_URL+"/api/auth/email",body).map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        res   => {console.warn("some thing")},
        err => { console.error("some bullshit")},
        () =>  {console.log('Authentication Complete')}
      );
    }); 
  }
```

**EDIT 2**
Just to add more insight to this. I'm using this isEmailAvailable function in a provider and using it as an async validator like this in my **signup.ts** page :

```
 constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, formBuilder : FormBuilder, 
       public globalVars : GlobalVars, public userData: UserData, public
       authService : AuthService)
{ 

     this.nav = navCtrl;
     this.signUpForm =  formBuilder.group({
     email :  [
        '',Validators.compose([]),authService.isEmailAvailable],
     password: ['',Validators.compose([
           Validators.maxLength(100),   
           Validators.minLength(6),
           Validators.required,
           Validators.pattern(globalVars.getPasswordPattern().toString())])]
     });
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the request is not triggered? Are you sure `this.http.post(...)` is called at all?

Comment: Let me edit and post the whole function body. Even the promise inside which this http.post is also has console.log

Comment: Be more specific about what's wrong. (1) can you confirm that the method is called? (2) that the http request is made? (3)  that the server script received an responded?

Comment: 1) Yes I Can confirm the method is called
2) If you have failed to see the title of question it quite explains what's wrong

Comment: I didn't fail to see it but it didn't make sense. If you call the code why shouldn't it be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I **FINALLY** got it **working** in my service by manually injecting http provider inside this service. For some reason the usual way of setting the provider reference in the constructor was working as I was using

**THIS DID NOT WORK**

```
http : any;
constructor (httpService : Http)
{
  this.http = httpService;
}
```

this way, it wasn't working as

### this.http.post in isEmailAvailable() function

**UPDATED:**  **THIS DID WORK**

```
isEmailAvailable(control : Control) {

         // Manually inject Http
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
    let http = injector.get(Http);

    return new Promise(resolve => {
       let body =  JSON.stringify({username:control.value});

       let header = new Headers();
       header.append("Content-Type" , "application/json");

         // HERE I'm using manually injected http 

       return http.post(MyApp.BASE_URL+"/api/auth/email",body,{ headers: header}).map(res => res.json())
           .subscribe(
                res   => {console.warn("some thing")},
                err => { console.error("some bullshit")},
                () =>  {console.log('Authentication Complete')}
            );

 });
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code,  At which point does the promise resolve or reject? I don't see it here.

Comment: @BeetleJuice my problem was that the http call was never being triggered in the chrome dev tools. I got it triggered with this code as I've explained. The rest I'll do tonight since this already made me went sleepless for 2 straight days.

Answer (score 0):

Just removing `Promise.resolve(...)` should do:

```
public isEmailAvailable(control : Control) {

  let body =  JSON.stringify({username: control.value});
  console.log(body);
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  return this.http.post(MyApp.BASE_URL+"/api/auth/email",body).map(res => res.json())

  .do(res   => {console.warn("some thing")})
  .catch(err => { console.error("some bullshit"); return Observable.of([err]);})
  .toPromise().then(() =>  {console.log('Authentication Complete')});
```

Ensure you have everything imported (`do`, `catch`, `of`, `toPromise`)

Comment: But its being used as an async validator call so I have to return a Promise, is it something I should be bashed about? :(

Comment: I updated my answer. I haven't tried but it looks like async validators also support `Observable` not only `Promise` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6fd5bc075d70879c487c0188f6cd5b148e72a4dd/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/validators.ts#L73. You might need to add `take(1)` so the observable closes after the first event. This is at least currently an issue with the router. If you are returning an observable, then you must not subscribe yourself because subscribing returns a `Subscription`. You have to leave subscribing to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use promises. And you don't want to call `.subscribe()` within the function itself. It's the calling code that should subscribe on the Observable that the function returns. I would do:

```
public isEmailAVailable(control:Control): Observable<any>{
   let body = ...;
   let headers = ...;
   let options = new RequestOptions();
   options.headers = headers;

   //suppose your server returns TRUE if email is available
   return this.http.post('...', body, headers).map(res => res.json())
            //async validators should return NULL if field is valid
            //or an object with the failure reason
            .map(res => res?null: {'Email is unavailable':true});   
}
```

By the way your original code does not include the headers in the POST request. I've addressed that as well.

**Addendum:** If you have to return a promise, use this `return` instead:

```
return new Promise ((resolve) => {
    //assumes your server returns TRUE if email is available
    this.http.post(...).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
        //validator expects NULL when input is valid
        res => res? resolve(null): resolve ({'Email unavailable':true})
    );
});
```

You can see it working [in this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ercprJ8XeqnYyqyseLHN?p=preview). When `null` is outputted, the input is considered valid. When an object is outputted, it's considered invalid.

Comment: I have to return a promise since this function is being called in the formBuilder as an asyncValidator

Comment: @AdilSarwar updated my answer to show you how to return a promise instead.

Comment: I was returning promise in the beginning as well. Promise works fine as long as there is no http call involved in it. MY Problem involves HTTP inside the promise to validate the email from server.